# How to use webclient to create a directory when uploading a file in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, webclient

I am trying with below code, to Upload a document in **remote server**, but it shows an Error "The given path's format is not supported."

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{

                  client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(UserName, Password);

                  Directory.CreateDirectory(@"https://Sample.com/Folders/Test Folder/");     //Error shown here

                  client.UploadFile("https://Sample.com/Folders/Test Folder/", "POST" , @"C:\\Sample Document.docx");                

  }
```

How can I create the necessary directories with webclient ?

Comment: String path = Path.Combine(strPath,"Name","FileName");

Comment: Put this path to CreateDirectory function

Comment: Hi,@vishuminhas, I tried with `String path = Path.Combine(strPath,"Name","FileName"); ` but i didn't get any result I got same error

Answer (score 2):

You could try like below

```
//File Path
string filepath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Folders/Test Folder/");  
if (!Directory.Exists(filepath))
{
     Directory.CreateDirectory(filepath);
}
```

Comment: Hi,@ChandanKumar, I have Two websites (Ex: A & B) But here I need to Move a file from Website A to B while this process I need to create first directory in Website B by using credentials  only I enter website B. But your code same application only it's create the directory

Comment: That you didn't mention in your question. in your question you have mentioned that "Directory.CreateDirectory(@"https://Sample.com/Folders/Test Folder/");     //Error shown here"

Comment: Modify your question as per your requirement or post a new question.

Comment: In my question, I mentioned to  create a directory within remote server